# What is the format of DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT?

Tags: directx11, depth-buffer

I'm trying to read the values in a depth texture of type `DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT`.

I know this means "24 bits for depth, 8 bits for stencil" ["A 32-bit z-buffer format that supports 24 bits for depth and 8 bits for stencil."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb173059%28VS.85%29.aspx), but how do you interpret those 24 bits?

It's clearly not going to be a 32-bit int, and it's not going to be a 32-bit float.  If it is an integer value, how "far away" is a value of "1" in the depth texture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an Unsigned NORMalized float, which is a floating-point value between 0.0 and 1.0.

EDIT:
To clarify, the Depth component is accessed as a float, and the Stencil component is accessed as an unsigned integer.

Comment: _UINT indicates that it's quite clearly not a float.

Comment: @mh01 Actually the `D24` part is `UNORM`, [and he's right](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd607323(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: Check the DX SDK - UNORM - "Unsigned normalized integer; which is interpreted in a resource as an unsigned integer, and is interpreted in a shader as an unsigned normalized floating-point value in the range [0, 1]" - from the shader perspective he's right, from the resource perspective he's totally wrong.

Comment: No, look carefully. I believe UNORM refers to a float datatype.

Comment: Sorry but that's a direct quote from the DX SDK page for DXGI_FORMAT - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb173059%28v=vs.85%29.aspx - look at "Format Modifiers" towards the bottom.  The data type is explicitly specified as unsigned integer by the documentation but it is interpreted as float in your shader - read it on the CPU and you'll get 24-bit uints, not 24-bit floats.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some demo code which shows how it works:

```
// create a temporary texture 
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc; 
depthStencilTexture->GetDesc(&desc); 
desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING; 
desc.BindFlags = 0; 
desc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ; 
desc.MiscFlags = 0; 

ID3D11Texture2D* tmpTexture = nullptr; 
HRESULT hr = getDevice()->CreateTexture2D(&desc, nullptr, &tmpTexture); 

// Copy depth buffer
getImmediateContextD3D()->CopyResource(tmpTexture, depthStencilTexture); 

// access depth buffer
D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mappedRes; 
getImmediateContextD3D()->Map(tmpTexture, 0, D3D11_MAP_READ, 0, &mappedRes); 

unsigned int* color = (unsigned int*)mappedRes.pData;

// Extract 24 depth bits
float depth = static_cast<float>(color & 0x00FFFFFF); 
depth /= 16777216f; // divide bei 2^24

// compute a grayscale value [0;255]
unsigned char colorValue = static_cast<unsigned char>(depth * 255.0f);
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally for your texture (or rather the SRV you'll create) you use a format in the same "type" family, in this case DXGI_FORMAT_R24G8_TYPELESS - then when you sample it in your shader you just use a .r swizzle to get the depth value out (in 0..1 range).  You should not, of course, be reading it back to the CPU - how to interpret the data is going to be the least of your problems if you do.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem by using `DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT` in my depth texture instead.  It turned out that the z-buffer is all floats between 0.0f and 1.0f.